# dynamically change ng-repeat filter using params from ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-sref

So I have a custom filter set up in my ng-repeat list which I can change dynamically using different buttons with the same page.

My question is, how do I go about changing this filter, with a value outside of the page.

To clarify, I have an ng-repeat list on my 'list.view.html' and I would like to be able to press a button on my homepage, which includes a filter value, and load the 'list.view.html' with the filtered results including the param of the button on my homepage.

To iterate further,

above my ng-repeat on list.view.html, I include buttons like so:

```
<button class="sortBy" ng-click="myFilter =  { statusOpen : true }">Open</button>
```

Which updates my ng-repeat to only include items where the statusOpen boolean evaluates to true.

Here is the filter in my ng-repeat

```
<li class="list-group-item animate-repeat" data-ng-repeat="task in vm.tasks | filter:search | filter:myFilter>
```

How would I achieve the same result by clicking a button on the homepage which routes to the list.view.html page with filtered results?

I have tried setting a param filter in the controller for the list.view.html however I couldn't get it to work.

e.g `<a ui-sref="tasks.list({ myFilter = { onlineTask : 'true' } })">` on my homepage and :: on my client.routes.js

```
 params: {
       myFilter: null
 }
```

**console error message**

angular.js:11706 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '=' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 12 of the expression [{ myFilter = { onlineTask : 'true' } }] starting at [= { onlineTask : 'true' } }].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.20/$parse/syntax?p0=%3D&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=12&p3=%7B%20myFilter%20%3D%20%7B"

I am just looking for some general direction on how to proceed with this please.

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that setting needed params in angular-ui filter is the best way to achive what you want.

You just have to remember to:

1. Set up you URL properly (include param in URL) and process params using `$stateParams` service in yout controller. You may use array if you have more then one filter:

   ```
   $stateProvider
   .state('search', {
     url: "/search/?myFilter",
     templateUrl: 'search.html',
     controller: function ($stateParams) {
     // Get filter(s)
      console.log($stateParams.myFilter);
     }
   })
   ```
2. Properly assign your params in `ui-sref` (use colon!):

   `<a ui-sref="filter({ myFilter: ['filter1','filter2'] })">Go and filter</a>`

See example: http://plnkr.co/edit/QOHNYHVPRJ8iBm3Adjcj?p=preview

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, @przemod I am getting 'search/?myFilter=%5Bobject%20Object%5D' back as a response

Comment: ps. when I wrap in single quotation makes like so '{ onlineTask : true }' I get { onlineTask : true } as the filter in console log and search/?myFilter=%7B%20onlineTask%20:%20true%20%7D as the url

Comment: That's because you try to assing object to myFilter. To do that you have to specify params in other way. See example: http://plnkr.co/edit/FRXbkmUXINKi2qCmZGW0?p=preview
Unfortunately you won't see myFilter in URL.

Comment: you are an absolute life saver! Thanks so much! kudos to you